# NavigationView and custom Layout

Tags: android, android-design-library, navigationview, android-navigationview

I'm using the Designs Support Libraries `NavigationView` like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- put your main layout here -->
    <include layout="@layout/drawer_main_layout"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And I have set this menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_messages"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
            android:title="Messages" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_friends"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_headset"
            android:title="Friends" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_discussion"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
            android:title="Discussion" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Sub items">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
                android:title="Sub item 1" />
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
                android:title="Sub item 2" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Is there any way to use the NavigationView with a layout rather than a menu?

Comment: can you not just use the header view, nav_header file?

Comment: i want the header view and i want instead of menu to use a custom layout

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Here's how I solved it, and worked perfectly:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/nav_header" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/menuItemsListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Perfect way! I was tired of finding this but stupid of me why didn't I try expanding the closing tags! Nice One! I needed an explandable ListView actually!

Comment: does this draw the headerview unter the status bar?

Comment: Yes for sure, as its still a part of the NavigationView.

Comment: this is the only XML based working solution I have found so far. +1

Comment: Could anyone give reference link for this solution? because I tried this but getting problems.

Comment: Is it possible to get the "navigationView.setCheckedItem" system while using a recyclerview/listview?

Comment: @Shargotth you should change checked item status onResume of each screen of Menu

Comment: @HamzehSoboh what is @layout/nav_header?

Comment: @SibeliusSeraphini it's any other layout in your resources folder that you need as a header. The `include` line can be simply substituted by that layout.

Comment: just brilliant. was hunting for the solution since long.. God bless u :)

Comment: hey @HamzehSoboh , how can i get the call back when an view in the header or list clicked..not getting call back to onNavigationItemSelected().

Comment: @AlvinVarghese, sure because you're using a custom layout for the drawer. Just get the callback as you used to do in a normal listviews or recyclerviews. For the header, you can just set a normal click listener for it.

Comment: why do you need the NavigationView here? Can't you just use the LinearLayout instead of the NavigationView? What does it add?

Comment: Really better approach. I only recommend you guys to use one unique include instead. With that you gonna be able to keep ordered the menu-drawer interface separately.

Comment: hi all for me listview is not scrolling please help me

Comment: thanks so much. This should be in the official docs

Answer (score 38):

Yes You can ....
As I have done ...
Just take your custom layout inside the **NavigationView**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <ListView
            android:entries="@array/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The above code work for me...
But don't forget to remove `app:menu` from `NavigationView` . Otherwise it will overlap your custom view on the menu items.

Comment: The listview is appearing over the headerview. How to put it below headerview?

Comment: If u are using `ListView` as a child view then you can not use `NavigationView's` Header. So If you are using `ListView` you can add headerView in `ListView`.

Comment: When I added headerview in Listview, headerview disappeared. code      <ListView
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            android:entries="@array/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

Comment: Bro currently Design support library is buggy... You can do it. If you want to add headerview you have inflate it and add in listview programatically ..

Comment: What the NavigationView gives more if then we use ListView inside of it with a custom row as we are doing so far until now?

Comment: NavigationView is just for give a navigation in your app. You can also use it without drawer. It's just allow you to do a less code if you want simple label and image in your menu optional header that's it....

Comment: `LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); View listHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_list,null, false);
mDrawerList.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);`