# How to add custom views in the new NavigationView

Tags: android, navigationview, android-navigationview

I'm trying to add a switch as menuitem in [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) like this

[image]

I used the the actionViewClass attribute but it only shows the title.

```
<item
android:id="@+id/navi_item_create_notifications_sound"
android:title="Notifications Sounds"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat"
app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: you can refer my this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626324/navigationview-and-custom-layout/30644656#30644656

Comment: Did you solve this somehow?

Comment: The solution uptill now is to use the DrawerLayout with the old NavigationDrawer, I couldn't find a workaround using the NavigationVIew

Comment: Is that allowed regarding to the [Material Design Guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[The new support library 23.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html)

allows using a custom view for the items in Navigation View using `app:actionLayout` or using `MenuItemCompat.setActionView()`.

[image]

Here's how I managed to display a SwitchCompat

menu_nav.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/navi_item_1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_feed_grey_500_24dp"
            android:title="Feed" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navi_item_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_explore_grey_500_24dp"
            android:title="Explore" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navi_item_4"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_grey_500_24dp"
            android:title="Settings" />

    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/navi_item_create_notifications_sound"
            android:title="Notifications Sounds"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_swich"
            app:showAsAction="always" />

    </group>
</menu>
```

menu_switch.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    app:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:switchPadding="@dimen/spacing_small" />
```

To get the View and assign events to it, you should do :

```
SwitchCompat item = (SwitchCompat) navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).getActionView();
        item.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Logr.v(LOG_TAG, "onCheckedChanged" + isChecked);
            }
        });
```

Comment: very informative. Thnx. How to handle that switch change event ?

Comment: For example in this view it's the 4th item:
SwitchCompat item = (SwitchCompat) navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).getActionView();

item.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,         boolean isChecked) {
                Logr.v(LOG_TAG, "onCheckedChanged" + isChecked);
            }
        });

Comment: @atabouraya +1 for that, one doubt, Where should the SwitchCompact be initialized , I'm getting NullPointerException when trying to call setOnChecked,

Comment: You're getting NullPointerException when trying to access navigationView or SwitchCompat?

Comment: @atabouraya .. I have an issue...SwichCompat's thumb not switching their position on checked and unchecked, only color changes

Comment: I have another problem, how did you manage to make the text start from the same point the menu icons start ? for me the text is aligned with all the texts in the menu which leaves a lot of empty space on the left

Comment: If an item in the same group has an icon all the other items will have the same indentation, trying putting it in a separate group

Comment: I suggest using getMenu().findItem(itemID) method to get the menuItem object.

Comment: why don't better use getMenu/findItem(R.id.itemId) to find it easily?

Comment: Working but I am facing same problem which was faced by @MinaZaki Any solution?

Comment: @atabouraya accept any answer if your issue is resolved for SO users.

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution as you are using `NavigationView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/mSwitch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Night Mode" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your Switch into a separate Layout file:

Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_switch"
    android:title="Switch Title"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_my_switch"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Switch: "layout_my_switch.xml"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/my_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 'app:showAsAction' & 'app:actionLayout' is ignored in the NavigationView

Comment: Ok I didn't know that

Comment: @Gallal you should use 23.1.0 support libraries

Answer (score 1):

**[Update 03-03-2017]
The answer is outdated. Don't refer this. Refer the accepted answer.**

**Unfortunately currently NavigationView is not much allow customization ...**

You have to take the Customized ListView inside NavigationView.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

And create cell for this listview by taking TextView to left side and SwitchCompact to right side.

I hope it help you ...

Answer (score 0):

I used Below layout in Drawer Layout where Navigation View code has been used.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navi_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start|top"
        android:background="@color/navigation_view_bg_color"
        app:theme="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/drawer_header" />

            <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_menu" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score -5):

Are you looking for something like this, [image]

Then there is a custom component available in `Synfusion`, called [Navigation drawer](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/android/navigationdrawer).

You can find the respective documentation [here](http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/android/Documents/gettingstarted7.htm).

Man.! they offers [Community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) also.

Comment: he use NavigationView

Comment: `NavigationDrawer` is also `NavigationView` with some other additional features in it

Comment: where we can navigation from `LeftToRight`, `RightToLeft`, `TopToBottom` and `BottomToTop` with various  animation transitions

Comment: but why do you speak about Symfusion as he use standard Android ?

Comment: just an option available to use custom `NavigationView`, instead of trying complex workaorund in the native `Android`