# Android: Top NavigationView content gone

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, drawer

I use this code for navigation drawer

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:visibility="visible">
            <include
                layout="@layout/menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="ir.app.ir.live24.MainActivity"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#fff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In view android studio work correct :
http://i65.tinypic.com/wtvu4k.jpg

But in device after launch, top of menu has gone :
http://i68.tinypic.com/2nu0ub5.jpg

Next problem: clickable not work for menu

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**# Problem 1:**  Top of menu has gone.

**1.** Add `android:paddingTop="24dp"` to `menu` container `RelativeLayout` to show the `top` menu `TextView`.

**2.** Add `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` to `TextView` to show the `ripple effect` when `click` on it.

**Update your `menu.xml` as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="24dp"
    android:background="#fff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**FYI**, I have added `android:padding="16dp"` to all TextView's to give proper indents.

**# Problem 2: Clickable not work for menu.**

Set `onClick` listener to `TextView` to handle `click` events:

```
// From Activity onCreate() method

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ........................
    ...............................

    TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    textView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 1):

You should not add menu layout : in navigationView you can add menu directly..using `app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"`

use this layout:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"   //menu items in drawer
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="visible"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

now in res/menu/menu_navigation  add the menu items like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/profile_icon"
            android:title="Profile" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/settings_icon"
            android:title="Settings" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/about_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/about_us"
            android:title="About us" />

    </group>
</menu>
```

Here is the complete [Example](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html)

Comment: I dont use menu,group and item. i want use linear layout. can i ?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626324/navigationview-and-custom-layout..it may help

Comment: I check it. this answer add linear layout in <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView. like my code