# Android : Customising Navigation App Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have the below design to implement for the Android Navigation App Drawer of the app and I am confused how to go about it.

In my design, there is a black strip on the left side, which also has an image. My query is how do I create that space in the app drawer ?

I tried to add a Layout inside the app drawer but couldn't. It only allows 'Items' and 'Groups' to be added. What are my possible options ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:background="@color/colorBg"

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">


        android:background="@color/colorBg"
        <item
            android:id="@+id/myasset"
            android:background="@color/colorBg"
            android:title="My Asset" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/account"
            android:background="@color/colorBg"
            android:title="Account" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/howitworks"
            android:background="@color/colorBg"
            android:title="How it works" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/feedback"
            android:background="@color/colorBg"
            android:title="Feedback" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/legal"
            android:background="@color/colorBg"
            android:title="Legal" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/exit"
            android:background="@color/colorBg"
            android:title="Exit" />

    </group>



</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is Hamzeh Soboh's answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31716815/609235

Answer (score 0):

When you create new project in Android Studio, there is an option that help you build `NavigationDrawer`.

Default `activity_main.xml` in `layout`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

And you can do anything with `activity_main_drawe` or `nav_header_main`.

Comment: I tried to put a RelativeLayout inside the <menu> tags inside activity_main_drawer. It doesn't accept. Cant see anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can create **custom navigation drawer.** Try below tutorial :

[Custom navigation drawer 1](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/)

[Custom navigation drawer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23632492/8089770)