# Android Drawer Layout centered

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I'm not finding how to create a icon over text centered in the menu of a DrawerLayout.  Using standard Drawer layout file with menu items.  Tried adding android:gravity but that does not seem to help.  Thoughts?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/nav_backpack"
            android:icon="@drawable/person"
            android:title="Backpack" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_messages"
            android:icon="@drawable/messages"
            android:title="Messages" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_library"
            android:icon="@drawable/book"
            android:title="Library" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_calendar"
            android:icon="@drawable/calendar"
            android:title="Calendar" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_progress"
            android:icon="@drawable/book"
            android:title="Progress" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_account"
            android:title="Account" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_help"
            android:title="Help" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="none">
    <item android:title="About">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_version"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="v1.1(03)" />
        </menu>
    </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: you cant do that with the menu implementation as it is. I would suggest using a custom view; this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626324/navigationview-and-custom-layout/30644656

Comment: Wow this really does not exist in native Android huh?  Thought I was just overlooking something.  Seems so trivial.

Comment: Anyone else have a solution.  Can't believe I'm the only one trying this.

Comment: its not native as there is a specification for the navigation drawer component https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html# thats why you have to make it custom.